# How to delete or remove an email address which is added in AWS SES suppression list?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES for sending email. One of my email address is added in suppression list due to hard bounce. I need to remove this mail id from suppression list. How can I remve this? I tried Suppression List Removal from the left side pane of AWS SES. But still remains the same. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon SES suppression list is a list of recipient email addresses that have recently caused a hard bounce for any Amazon SES customer. If you try to send an email through Amazon SES to an address that is on the suppression list, the call to Amazon SES succeeds, but Amazon SES treats the email as a hard bounce instead of attempting to send it. An email address can remain on the suppression list for up to 14 days.

**If you are sure that the email address that you're trying to send to is valid, you can submit a suppression list removal request.It will be removed immediately.**

I guess the email address is invalid. Can you please post us the suppression email?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed by running aws cli command. :)